# logrotate stopped to work

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-14.04

For some reason my apache logs stopped to rotate. There is no error in logs, running manually `logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf` everything work normally. This is my apache conf file located in logrotate.d directory. I am on ubuntu 14.04

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log /var/www/*/log/*.log {
    daily
    size 30M
    missingok
    rotate 7
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    create 640 root adm
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
                if /etc/init.d/apache2 status > /dev/null ; then \
                    /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null; \
                fi;
    endscript
    prerotate
        if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
            run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
        fi; \
    endscript
}
```

What else should I check, to see where the problem is? Thank you.

Comment: The cronjob `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` and if it throws any errors?

Comment: @rda no, no errors at all. Everything runs smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Running command:-

```
sudo /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf
```

Show errors that logrotate refuses to work with insecure permissions, i.e. world writable.